# Type of Value is returned by getMeasuredHeight()?

Tags: android, height, return-value, return-type

i'm measuring the height of a view. I have the screen divided in two equal sections, A and B, so each one should be half of the screen in pixels.

Using this code i have de real pixel size of each one. In this case i get 1300 pixels.

```
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
final int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

But when i use view.getMeasuredHeigth() inside view.getViewTreeObserver() the value is smaller than the value obtained with the code above, in case i get almost half of before: 627 pixels:

```
final RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.contenedor_video);
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        final int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

....
```

My question is: What type of value is returned by getMeasuredHeight() method??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw measured height of this view. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight()

Answer (score 0):

Just to save one click to any other URL:
It **returns the value in Pixels, not in dp**.